# Как встроить переменную напрямую в код?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо вставить переменную напрямую в код. Чтобы вставить переменную в строку, надо перед "" написать f, а что нужно сделать для того что бы вставлять переменные в код?

```py
counter = 1
def regNewUser(password, email, username):
    newUser = user{counter} = [f"{password}", f"{email}", f"{username}"]
    return newUser
```

В этом коде в 3 строке вместо `{counter}` в код вставлялась переменная `counter`.
Подскажите, возможно ли это сделать, и если да, то как?

Comment: Научиться пользоваться массивами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно не пытаться создавать переменные с номерами в имени, а просто использовать список:

```
users = []


def regNewUser(password, email, username):
    newUser = [f"{password}", f"{email}", f"{username}"]
    users.append(newUser)
    return newUser
```

Кстати, если `password`, `email`, `useraname` - строки, то дополнительно оборачивать их в f-строки не нужно:

```
newUser = [password, email, username]
```