# Как задать имя переменной используя конкатенацию: строковое значение + порядковый номер? (Например, имя df_1 получается как "df_" + str(i), где i = 1)

Tags: python, pandas, переменные, concat

Цель такая: прочитать методом pandas.read_excel некоторое количество файлов, всегда разное, и "склеить" их, нарастив их содержимое одно под другим. Вот как выглядит мой код сейчас:

```
import pandas as pd
# читаем
df_01 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 1_01.07.22 - 07.07.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_02 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 1_08.07.22 - 14.07.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_03 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 1_17.06.22 - 23.06.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_04 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 1_24.06.22 - 30.06.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_05 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 2_01.07.22 - 07.07.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_06 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 2_08.07.22 - 14.07.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_07 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 2_17.06.22 - 23.06.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_08 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 2_24.06.22 - 30.06.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_09 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 3_01.07.22 - 07.07.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_10 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 3_08.07.22 - 14.07.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_11 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 3_17.06.22 - 23.06.22.xlsx', header=3)
df_12 = pd.read_excel('Результаты 3_24.06.22 - 30.06.22.xlsx', header=3)
# склеиваем
df = (
    df_01
    .append(df_02)
    .append(df_03)
    .append(df_04)
    .append(df_05)
    .append(df_06)
    .append(df_07)
    .append(df_08)
    .append(df_09)
    .append(df_10)
    .append(df_11)
    .append(df_12)
)
```

Файлы всегда стандартные, с одинаковым количеством столбцов и с шапкой одной высоты, поэтому хочется завернуть процедуру чтения файлов в функцию, которая бы сама генерировала имена переменных по шаблону "df_" + str(i). Как это сделать и возможно ли такое?

Comment: Зачем переменные с индексами, если сюда просятся списки? Или вы с ними еще не знакомы?

Comment: Со списками знаком, но достаточно поверхностно. Списки состоящие из чего вы имеете в виду? Вообще не давать имена датафреймам, а сразу загонять их в список?

Comment: загонять файлы в список и циклом перебирать.

Comment: Можно и так, но можно даже список имен файлов. Прочитал файл, append'ом подклеил к итоговому датафрейму (цикл for - замечательная вещь, если про неё не забывать). И, наконец, никогда не задавайте 2 вопроса в одном, это неудобно получается.

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Как встроить переменную напрямую в код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1315610/1365), [Как динамически создать переменную, в названии которой может содержаться значение другой переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/959006/1365)

Comment: @mrEvgenX, вот вы спрашиваете, "Зачем переменные с индексами"? Ну, например, чтобы перед склейкой файлов проверять, не поменялось ли количество столбцов, кодом типа `print(len(df_01.columns))`. Так прочитал **один** раз в переменные и дальше пользуешься ими быстренько, а читать каждый раз по новой (`print(len(pd.read_excel(f, header=3))) for f in file_names`) дольше получается. Тем дольше, чем больше файлов и чем больше они весят (КЭП)

Comment: @ВасилийБалин тогда используйте списки. Нумерованные переменные использовать не стоит никогда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше сделать как-то так. Используя списки и цикл for и по алгоритму "прочитал/приклеил/повторил".

```
import pandas as pd
# читаем
df = pd.read_excel('file_0.xlsx', header=3)
file_names = [
    'file_1.xlsx',
    # ...
]
for file_name in file_names:
    df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file_name, header=3))
```

Comment: начиная с pandas версии 1.4. append считается устаревшим, рекомендуется использовать вместо него concat, например, примерно так: `df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f,header=3) for f in files],ignore_index=True)`